# Value Error in polymorphism Django-Model association

Tags: python, django, django-models

I've followed [Django ContentTypes](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/contenttypes/), Then I created an app for tagging purpose.

*Like `django-taggit` or `tagging`*.

`tagging.models.py`:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.contrib.contenttypes import generic
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify

class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, max_length=100)

    def __unoicode__(self):
        return self.name

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        super(Tag, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

class TaggedItem(models.Model):
    tag = models.ForeignKey(Tag)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    object = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.tag.name
```

`blog.models.py`:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    content = models.TextField()

    ##
    tags = generic.GenericRelation(TaggedItem)
```

`blog.views.py`:

```
article = Article.objects.create(user=request.user)
article.title = form.cleaned_data['title']
article.body = form.cleaned_data['body']

##
tag_names = form.cleaned_data['tags'].split()
for tag_name in tag_names:
    tagged = TaggedItem(object=article, tag=tag_name)
    tagged.save()
article.save()
```

So, When I save or create new `article` I'll get this error:

```
Cannot assign "u'browser'": "TaggedItem.tag" must be a "Tag" instance.
```

*browser* is a tag string !!!

I think this error printed because I've declared `tag` as `ForeignKey` Relation in `TaggedItem`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert your tag strings into actual Tag objects.

```
for tag_name in tag_names:
    tag, created = Tag.objects.get_or_create(name=tag_name)
    tagged = TaggedItem(object=article, tag=tag)
tagged.save()
```

Comment: and what's that created object for?

Comment: The `get_or_create` method always returns the object plus a boolean to show whether it was newly created or not. Since you're not actually using it, you could use `_` in place of `created` to show it's a throw-away variable.